# Can't create instance of a class inside a folder

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create an instance for the class Sounds that's have this content:

```
class Sounds
{
    public static void getInformationSound() 
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(
            @"pack://application:,,,/Mah/Resources/Sounds/psl.wav");
        player.Play();
    }

    public void getErrorSound() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

the class `Sounds` is inside the folder `Tools` how you can see in the image:

[image]

I've tried to create an instance of a class `Sounds` and read the method like:

```
Sounds sd = new Sounds();
sd.getInformationSound();
```

sd is underlined in red and also the compiler show me this message:

> It is a field but is used as a type

What I doing wrong?

Comment: `getInformationSound` method is static, so you have to call it like this: `Sounds.getInformationSound();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access a `static` method via an instance of the class. Static methods are meant to be accessed via the `type`.

So you either have to remove the `static` from

```
public static void getInformationSound()
```

or access the method using the type:

```
Sounds.getInformationSound()
```

You might also want to have a look at what's written on MSDN about [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

`getInformationSound` is a [`static`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static) method. These are called with the type name. No instance is required. So call it like this:

```
Sounds.getInformationSound();
```

`Static` denotes things that are singular. They are part of no instance. `Static` often improves performance, but makes programs less flexible.